# Private pastebin site?

Tags: file-sharing

Is anyone aware of a site similar to pastebin but which allows "real" private pastes? ( read, require user/password or token to see the edit )

Paste bin has this "private" mode where if you prepend a magic word ( say : aaspdoifjapsdfoji.pastebin.com )  only those with the correct url may see the post, but I don't think this prevents from robots to crawl the site.

Comment: How would a robot find the page if it isn’t linked to anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepad.org allows you to make private pastes, as a bonus you can run your code to test output. If you click the small question mark beside private, it will explain that search engines should not be able to crawl them.

Comment: Private pastes at codepad are exactly same as pastebin.

Answer (score 3):

You can get pastebin source code and deploy on your server or hosting. And secure with password. Or look to some other open source pastebin app.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub's [Gists](http://gist.github.com/) can be marked as private, which will only allow you to see them.  You can't, afaik, add collaborators (like you can in full-fledged projects), so anyone who wants to see it has to have an ssh key added to your account.  That would be a good idea to put to them, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to make some compromises between convenience and privacy. Sites on a similar vein to pastebin are never going to guarantee any high level of privacy.

Sites where you can share encrypted rar files of code would allow pretty much guaranteed privacy, but obviously with the loss of pastebin-esque functionality.

Comment: https://mymsg2u.com/ seems to be down

Comment: Heh, 11 year old answer :D. I'll remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iPaste.eu allows to protect your pastes by password. A search engine bot will get only a page where will be written that the paste is password protected.

Comment: http://www.ipaste.eu/ seems to be off line

Answer (score 0):

With  http://fnpaste.com/ you have a lot of options:

**1st: Visibility**

• Hidden
A hidden paste is viewable by anyone with the paste ID or URL, but will not show up on any public paste lists or be indexed by search engines. This is the default visibility setting for new pastes.
Private

•Private pastes are only accessible via the secure paste URL, which contains a **special hash** code to ensure that no one guesses or brute-forces the paste URL. Anyone you give the secure URL to can view your paste. 
(example: http://fnpaste.com/L8AW?**hash=6b4ace7bd80fa2e5f57bc276ee2473c0** )

**2nd: Encryption Password**

•If you provide an encryption password, your paste will be encrypted so that only people with the password can view it.

256-bit AES encryption and decryption is handled locally in your browser using the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library, so the unencrypted text or password is never sent to us.

We have no way of decrypting pastes without your password, so please don't lose it!

**3rd: Paste Expiration Date**

•You can control when your paste expires. By default, pastes do not expire and will live happily forever.

**4rd: Paste Availability Date**

• You can control when your paste will be available to the world. By default, pastes are available immediately after creation.

Try using this along with the Email Notification option for sending someone your top-secret spy data at a specific date/time. Once created, your paste will be emailed to the recipient automatically (unless it is deleted before the availability date!)

**5th: Email Notification**

**6th: Delete Code**

Comment: http://fnpaste.com/  seems to be off line